# How can I substitute the CSP nonce value in Angular index.html using Apache httpd.conf and mod_cspnonce?

Tags: angular, apache, content-security-policy, httpd.conf, nonce

Tried to setup CSP nonce in angular application hosted on apache httpd server using **mod_cspnonce** module.

Was able to construct the below policy and could see the response headers holds correct nonce- value.

`Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src http: https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e'"`

[image: Nonce received in response header]

However, I couldn't substitute or setup the same nonce in index.html using httpd.conf.

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://../example1.js" nonce="CSP_NONCE"></script>
<script src="https://../example2.js" nonce="CSP_NONCE"></script>
<script src="https://../example3.js" nonce="CSP_NONCE"></script>
```

I've tried couple of options to replace CSP_NONCE keyword in index.html mentioned in [csplite](https://csplite.com/csp220/#mod_cspnonce)

- **mod_substitute** ([link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_substitute.html#substitute))

```
<Location />
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Substitute "s|CSP_NONCE|nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e|i"
</Location>
```

- **mod_sed** ([link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_sed.html#sampleconf))

```
<Directory "/">
    AddOutputFilter Sed html
    OutputSed "s/CSP_NONCE/nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e/g"
</Directory>
```

Both these options return only string literal in the response, but not the expected substituted nonce value.

References:

https://csplite.com/csp220

https://github.com/wyday/mod_cspnonce

Any suggestions would be helpful!